# How to trigger second event when the other event is completed?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

```
var a:PolygonEvent;
a.addEventListener("Clearpage",clpag,false,0,true);
a.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,showselectpoint,false,0,true);
```

I am trying to trigger the showselectoint after the first clearpage is done complete when I normally call these two events one after another it executes the second and first just after one another it doesnt wait for the first event to be finished. I have written this code now but it shows an error. Can anyone tell me how I can do it? I just need to declare a with some type I dont get what should be its type.

Answer (score 0):

You may call showselectpoint at the end of clpag.

More elegant way is create a Task class, and the Task has an execute function to do its job,when its task finished,and has a func variable to do the real job(execute will cal func(), 
in your case, func will be clpag  and showselectpoint, you can create a Task and set target function to its func.

The task will dispath an event. So you need a TaskList class to contain a list of Task, and add an event listener on task finished event, when one task finishs, execute next task.